# Google Charts - setting explorer bounds / interval

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts with the "explorer" option (see example http://jsfiddle.net/KArng/101/) to drag / scroll to change the chart data view range:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
var y = 50;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        y += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        data.addRow([i, y]);
    }

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    explorer: {
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn:0.1,
        maxZoomOut:4

    },

});
}
```

In this example, the OX axis (hAxis) has values from 0 to 1000 and the chart can be zoomed-in using the mouse scroll and then dragged to update the data view.

But how do I set the bounds (OX min/max interval) programatically? For example, when the chart is loaded and displayed, I want to show the initial min/max to be 500 / 750 (to have a default zoom let's say).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the view window for each axis.

```
vAxis: { 
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow:{
            max:1000,
            min:0
          }
        }
hAxis: {
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow:{
            max:1000,
            min:0
          }
        }
```

Comment: The [0, 1000] is the full interval, i need something like [400, 600]. The problem is that if i set the viewWindow, I cannot drag the view outside those bounds, it just gets stuck: http://jsfiddle.net/KArng/102/

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this within Google Charts but you can add your own buttons for moving around - http://jsfiddle.net/KArng/106/